# How to prove that semi-confluence implies confluence in Coq?

Tags: coq

I use the definitions provided by `Coq.Relations` and I have the following definitions :

```
Definition joinable (x:A) (y:A) : Prop :=
  exists z, (clos_refl_trans A R x z) /\ (clos_refl_trans A R y z).

Notation "X ↓ Y" := (joinable X Y) (at level 70, right associativity).
Notation "X → Y" := (R X Y) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "X →* Y" := (clos_refl_trans A R X Y) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "X ⇆ Y" := (clos_refl_sym_trans A R X Y) (at level 75, right associativity).

Definition confluent : Prop := forall x y1 y2, (x →* y1 /\ x →* y2) -> (y1↓y2).
Definition semi_confluent : Prop := forall x y1 y2, (x → y1 /\ x →* y2) -> (y1↓y2).
```

Here is what I have :

```
Theorem semi_confluent_confluent : semi_confluent -> confluent.
Proof.
  unfold confluent, semi_confluent, joinable.
  intros. destruct H0. induction H0.
  - apply H with (x := x). split. auto. auto.
  - exists y2. split. auto. auto.
  - admit.
Admitted.
```

I tried to use induction on :

- H0 : x →* y1

But it seems that I'm stuck on the last case (transitivity). I tried several things for the last case like induction on (x →* z) but it seems to lead me to an unprovable statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bit easier to prove the theorem by induction on `clos_refl_trans_1n` relation (it's equivalent to `clos_refl_trans`).
Because it gives us two cases : the reflexive case and the case when we actually "make an `R`-step" and we can easily use the semi-confluence property, which requires an `R`-step.

I slightly changed the definitions of `confluent` and `semi_confluent` to avoid wrappings/unwrappings related to conjunction. This doesn't affect anything, because the result is logically equivalent to the original.

I should also point out that as in many cases we need to generalize our statement before performing induction.

```
Definition confluent : Prop := forall x y1 y2, x →* y1 -> x →* y2 -> (y1↓y2).
Definition semi_confluent : Prop := forall x y1 y2, x → y1 -> x →* y2 -> (y1↓y2).

Hint Constructors clos_refl_trans.

Theorem semi_confluent_confluent : semi_confluent -> confluent.
Proof.
  intros Hsemi x y1 y2 Hxy1 Hxy2.
  unfold semi_confluent, joinable in *.
  generalize dependent y2.
  induction (clos_rt_rt1n _ _ _ _ Hxy1) as [| x y1' y1 HRxy1' Hy1'y1 IH]; intros y2 Hxy2.
  - now exists y2.
  - apply clos_rt1n_rt in Hy1'y1.
    specialize (Hsemi x y1' y2 HRxy1' Hxy2) as (z & Hy1'z & Hy2z).
    specialize (IH Hy1'y1 z Hy1'z) as (w & Hy1w & Hzw).
    exists w.
    split; auto.
    now apply rt_trans with (y := z).
Qed.
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something. Having the `clos_refl_trans_1n` to reason with is way better than the other def !

Comment: Nice ! I didn't know the existence of `clos_refl_trans_1n` as well. What does the "&" symbol stand for ? How can I learn about the kind of syntactic tricks you used ?

Comment: Where does the `clos_rt_rt1n` identifier you used come from ?

Comment: (1) `(p1 & ... & pn)` is convenient to use for destructing (nested) right-associative binary constructs, e.g. `/\` or `exists`. It's often easier to use -- compare `(z & H1 & H2)` to `[z [H1 H2]]`. (2) The manual is a hard, but very useful read (btw, see §8.3.2 for intro-patterns); people post surprising things on Stackoverflow (I especially recommend answers by Arthur Azevedo De Amorim (and his blog), ejgallego, gallais, and Ptival); you can subscribe to the Coq Club mailing list; reading source code of the stdlib and some major libraries (like mathcomp) is very illuminating.

Comment: `clos_rt_rt1n` comes from the library `Coq.Relations.Operators_Properties` (`Locate clos_rt_rt1n.`), which gets imported automatically when you import `Coq.Relations.Relations`.

Comment: A last question : how can I use the "specialize...as" syntax ? It doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: @EngBoris Strangely enough it is not documented in the manual. I checked the proof with Coq 8.6 and it works. It's like `specialize (<hyp> ...); destruct <hyp> as ...`, it should change a general `<hyp>` hypothesis into a special case and then destruct it.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Ok, I just updated my version of Coq. The syntax seems to change often (and the GUI of CoqIDE as well).